# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ajax row select

Tags: jsf, primefaces

If i select a row in my Datatable i always following :  **Feb 24, 2014 1:01:42 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
Information: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch** . The Problem is ajax tag. If i remove it i get no exception

i use primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1

```
<p:dataTable id="inboxTable" var="task_toUser" value="#{taskboxBean.taskboxInboxList}" paginator="true"
            widgetVar="inboxTable" rows="5" selection="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox}"
            selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{task_toUser.ID}" emptyMessage="" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":contentForm, :postForm:tabViewPosts:trashTable,  :postForm:tabViewPosts:inboxTable, :postForm:tabViewPosts:sentTable "
                listener="#{taskboxBean.onTaskboxRowSelect}" />


            <p:column headerText="Post" filterBy="FROM_USER.FIRST_NAME" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{task_toUser.TASKBOX.FROM_USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task_toUser.TASKBOX.FROM_USER.LAST_NAME} (#{task_toUser.TASKBOX.FROM_USER.EMAIL})" />


                <p:commandButton disabled="true" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed"  rendered="#{!task_toUser.IS_SEEN}"/>
                <p:commandButton disabled="true" style="float:right"  icon="ui-icon-mail-open"  rendered="#{task_toUser.IS_SEEN}"/>
                <br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{task_toUser.TASKBOX.TASKTYPE.NAME}   " />
                <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold; " value="#{task_toUser.TASKBOX.TASKBOX_SUPPLIER.NEW_SUPPLIER.NAME}"/>
                <br />
                <h:outputText value="#{task_toUser.TASKBOX.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: maybe it's expecting something else in the ajax attribute. what do you want to do on this event?

Comment: You have p:ajax set on row select event but where is the listener ? Listener is the action should be perform but you're missing it. Either you add listener or remove this tag from your code.

Comment: i edited the code see above. I add a listner and a update attribute

Comment: @bvb1909 post your managed bean code.

Comment: hi should I poste the whole or only the methode ?
in the method only put an System.out. Before the message their come the excpetion and after them my text

Comment: @bvb1909 where is the implementation of `onTaskboxRowSelect`?

Comment: i post an new Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem. The problem is that the ArrayList is from another Type than the Selection and xhtml casted it automatically.